# ng-hide based on parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a navbar in my main controller and I want a link to show/hide based on the url. I'm using ui-router for routing so I've thought I could use $state for getting the parent state of the current state but I don't know how. I've done this before to get the current state and it works

```
<li ng-hide="$state.current.name === 'new-sector'">
    <a ui-sref="new-sector">+ Add new sector!</a>
</li>
```

But now, I'm working with nested states so the current state is new-sector.location.
My problem is that I want that link to hide in all new-sector child states!

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: would you be able to provide a plnkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `$state.includes(stateName)` to check  if the current active state is equal to or is the child of the state `stateName`.

Here is an [example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4vKl4SSlegfG22RUSECu?p=preview) that shows the usage of `$state.includes`.

More details on the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params)

Comment: yes.  `ng-hide="$state.includes('new-sector')"`.  You'll have to provide $state on the scope though.  I tend to use a `app.run(function($state, $scope) { $scope.$state = $state; });` block  to add it to the root scope.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Chris T's answer:

To avoid having to both create a controller and inject $scope and $state for each state, you can simply use .run() and store your state information in the rootscope.

```js
app.run( function($state, $rootScope){
    $rootscope.stateHolder = $state.current;
  }
);
```

Furthermore, if you're only interested in the name of the state, just add .name at the end of $state.current.

This can then be easily accessed by:

```html
<div ng-hide="stateHolder.name == 'home'">
  This will be hidden on the home page.
</div>
```